# AngularJS - Calling wookmark layout without using $timout

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, pinterest

I am currently involved in a task to create pinterest like thumbnails using wookmark plugin and angularjs.  On which i am able to display thumbnails using $timeout of 10 seconds because server taking time to respond. I wanted to call the layout after the data completely gets loaded. I have tried with promise but no luck.

Is there any way to call the Wookmark layout without using $timeout?

my code belows:

```
myApp.controller("MyCtrl", ['$scope', '$timeout', 'eventData', function($scope,  $timeout, eventData) {
    function init() {
        $scope.publicstreams = [];
        $scope.publicstreams = eventData.getEvent(0);
        $timeout(initWookmark, 10000);
    }

    function initWookmark() {
        var options = {
            autoResize: true, // This will auto-update the layout when the browser window is resized.
            container: $('#tiles'), // Optional, used for some extra CSS styling
            offset: 5, // Optional, the distance between grid items
            flexibleWidth: 310 // Optional, the maximum width of a grid item
        };
        var handler = $('#tiles li');
        $('#tiles').imagesLoaded(function() {
            // Prepare layout options.
            // Get a reference to your grid items.
            // Call the layout function.
            handler.wookmark(options);
        });
        handler.wookmark(options);
    }
    init();
}]);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There is another option called angular-deckgrid. Check it out.

Answer (score 2):

Thanking God!

Finally I figured it out myself. I set the delay to 0 in $timeout and it worked.

**How?**

$timeout actually executes after the DOM has finished rendering in browser. So even the delay of 0 millisecond works.